# Как закрыть или выйти из терминального режима plink

Tags: cmd, terminal

в исполняемом cmd запускается plink и отправляется файл по терминалу в модем и одновременно пишет в лог

```
@echo on
mode com1 115200,n,8,1,p >> plink.log
at.cmd | plink -serial com1 >> plink.log
```

файл at.com содержит:

```
@echo on
echo ATI;+COPS?;+csq;+CIMI;+CGSN;+cclk?
timeout /t 1 /nobreak >nul 2>&1
echo AT+CGDCONT=1,"IP"
timeout /t 1 /nobreak >nul 2>&1
```

*окно терминала открыта и после выполнения plink не заканчивает сессию терминала и не выходит в CMD.*

**Что и куда добавить чтобы plink вышел в CMD?**

[plink won't return to command prompt - читал, но ничего не понял как применит к моему случаю :(](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21456402/plink-wont-return-to-command-prompt)

Answer (score 0):

Добавить в конец бат-файла at.cmd команду на остановку процесса plink.exe и всего делов-то. Можно ещё попытаться отправлять команды не через перенаправление команд батника at.cmd в программу plink, а просто запустить утилиту plink в режиме работы батника. Тогда по окончании выполнения команд утилита обязана завершить работу. У неё, кажется, для этого есть параметр: **-m**
Пример работы в режиме считывания команд с файла:

```
plink -m at.txt -serial com1
```

Где в файле at.txt лежат нужные команды.

А, собственно, к данному конкретному вопросу имеется такой ответ. В конец файла at.cmd нужно добавить команду:

```
taskkill /f /im plink.exe
```

Естественно, это сработает корректно в том случае, когда в памяти запущен только 1 экземпляр этой утилиты (иначе "прибьет" все имеющиеся).

Comment: добавление taskkill /f /im plink.exe в at.cmd работает, а plink -m at.txt -serial com1 - не закрывает окно. спасибо. выбрал способ с килл